# Как отправить почтой содержимое файла, полученного через input type="file"?

Tags: php, html

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно отправить содержимое файла, загруженного через форму, на определённый почтовый адрес. Сделал кучу попыток, но так ни к чему и не пришёл.
Максимум, что я мог сделать:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="qq">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
        if (!empty($_FILES['qq']) && !$_FILES['qq']['error']) {
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->addAddress('test@weeee.ru', 'John Doe');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
    $mail->msgHTML("My message body");
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['qq']);
    $r = $mail->send();
}
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Буду благодарен, если поможете!

Comment: и какие проблемы с этим кодом?

Comment: ```$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['qq']['tmp_name']);``` https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files
@splash58 в том что хранится в переменной $_FILES  :)

Answer (score 0):

Честно признаюсь, не проверял, но скорее всего это должно работать:

```html
<html>
    <!-- 1.Вы не установили "multipart/form-data" для "enctype" -->
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="test_file">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
</html>
```

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    /* 2.Предлагаю использовать is_uploaded_file для проверки */
    if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES["test_file"]["tmp_name"]))
        exit();
    require "PHPMailerAutoload.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->addAddress("test@mail.ru", "Ivan Ivanov");
    $mail->Subject = "PHPMailer file sender";
    $mail->msgHTML("Test message.");
    /* 3.Нужно использовать "tmp_name" */
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES["test_file"]["tmp_name"]);
    $result = $mail->send();
}
```